# Joomla 4 javascript processing of the paginator

Tags: joomla-4.x, pagination

Good day.
I output the paginator

```
<?php echo $pagination->getListFooter(); ?>
```

Output

```
<nav class="pagination__wrapper" aria-label="Нумерування сторінок">
        <div class="pagination pagination-toolbar text-center">
            <ul class="pagination ms-auto mb-4 me-0">
                ..................
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a aria-label="Перейти на сторінку 2" href="#" onclick="document.adminForm.limitstart.value=20; Joomla.submitform();return false;" class="page-link">2</a>
                </li>
                ................
            </ul>
        </div>
</nav>
```

Javascript code

```
jQuery(document).on('click', 'ul.pagination li a', function (event) {
.....
```

Two questions:
1.How to add a class to the line

```
<ul class="pagination ms-auto mb-4 me-0">
```

2. How to use javascript to check that the administrative part is active?
   On php this `if ($app->isClient('administrator'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid template overrides and just want to have it like that just for your component, then you could do that by overriding the `Pagination::getPaginationLinks` function, and get it to use a layout from your component rather than the Joomla layout.

To do this you need to first create your own layout, which mirrors 'joomla.pagination.links'.

Then you need to create your own pagination class which extends the Joomla one:

```
namespace …; // fill in your namespace here

use Joomla\CMS\Pagination\Pagination;

class Mypagination extends Pagination 
{

public function getPaginationLinks($layoutId = 'joomla.pagination.links', $options = [])
{
    // Include your own layout below:
    $layoutId = 'my.pagination.links';

    $list = [
        'prefix'       => $this->prefix,
        'limit'        => $this->limit,
        'limitstart'   => $this->limitstart,
        'total'        => $this->total,
        'limitfield'   => $this->getLimitBox(),
        'pagescounter' => $this->getPagesCounter(),
        'pages'        => $this->getPaginationPages(),
        'pagesTotal'   => $this->pagesTotal,
    ];

    return LayoutHelper::render($layoutId, ['list' => $list, 'options' => $options]);
}
}
```

Then provide a function `getPagination` in your model; this will override the Joomla ListModel `getPagination` function. This function should then instantiate your pagination class.

```
use <your namespace prefix>\Mypagination; 

public function getPagination()
{
    // Get a storage key.
    $store = $this->getStoreId('getPagination');

    // Try to load the data from internal storage.
    if (isset($this->cache[$store])) {
        return $this->cache[$store];
    }

    $limit = (int) $this->getState('list.limit') - (int) $this->getState('list.links');

    // Create the pagination object and add the object to the internal cache.
    $this->cache[$store] = new Mypagination($this->getTotal(), $this->getStart(), $limit);

    return $this->cache[$store];
}
```

I haven't tested this out, but I think it should work.

Answer (score 2):

The HTML above is output by the joomla layout in layouts/joomla/pagination/links.php.

So you can create a template override by going to your template Details and Files, and creating an override on Layouts joomla/pagination. Then you can edit the links.php to add in an extra class into the ul element.

If you're not familiar with creating overrides then you can find out about them in [Layout Overrides in Joomla](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla) and [Joomla Improved Override Management](https://magazine.joomla.org/all-issues/july-2022/joomla-override-management), for example.

The layouts you create are specific to the template, so if you want different attributes in the ul class in both the front end and the back end then you need to create 2 template overrides, one for your site template and one for your administrator template. You can obviously put different attributes in each, and then look at the attributes within your javascript to determine whether you're on the administrator or site side. Or using the same code, put this into your back-end and front-end overrides ...

```
<ul class="pagination ms-auto mb-4 me-0 <?php echo Factory::getApplication()->getName(); ?> ">
```

which will add 'site' or 'administrator' into the class list.

Another way is to pass data down to javascript using the joomla `getScriptOptions` function, described in [Adding JavaScript and CSS to the page](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Adding_JavaScript_and_CSS_to_the_page).

```
$app = Factory::getApplication();
$adminOrSite = $app->getName();
$app->getDocument()->addScriptOptions('myvars', $adminOrSite);
```

and then in javascript:

```
var admin_or_site = Joomla.getOptions('myvars');
```